# Selenium WebDriver(C#)-Error-CS0246-The type or namespace 'WebDriverManager' couldn't be found(are youmissing using directive or assembly reference?)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting below error while while working on my seleniumWebdriver via .net c#. I am getting this issue with a new project only. Older projects are working fine.

> - Severity: Error
> - Code: CS0246
> - Description: **The type or namespace name 'WebDriverManager' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**
> - Project: AutomationTwo
> - File: `C:\Users\JagSingh\source\repos\Practice Project\AutomationTwo\UnitTest1.cs`
> - Line: 4
> - Suppression State: Active

[image: Photo showing above error in import]

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if you have installed the packages in the new project. Try to also check if the package you have installed targets the correct version of the target framework of your program.

[Check Nuget Package Installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHmyL.png)

Based on the reference link below, one issue that may cause this error to display is the following:

- Did you reference the assembly that was built against a higher framework version than the target framework of the program? Or did you reference the project that is targeting a higher framework version than the target framework of the program? For example, you work on the project that is targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1 and use the type from the project that is targeting .NET Framework 4.7.1. Then you get error CS0246.

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0246

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).